# object instantiation

Tags: .net

I am new To .NET Programming, Can anyone please explain me about object instantiation with the real time example?

Answer (score 5):

```
object handle = new object();
```

"handle" is not the object itself, but a handle to the object. This is quite important to understand :) You can have multiple handles to the same object; for example:

```
object handle1 = new object(); //Here's the instantiation
object handle2 = handle1; //No instantiation

//These methodcalls happens on the same instance of object.
handle1.ToString();
handle2.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new object(); // instantiation 
object o; //declaration
o = new object(); // assignment and instantiation

object p = new object(); //all three
```